# Force a makefile rule to be executed based on value of a makefile variable

Tags: makefile, command-line-arguments, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a makerule which is forced to execute when command line argument changes. I'm assigning this commandline argument to a makefile variable **`ARG`**.

When I execute the makefile for the first time , the rule for **`dep.mk`** is executed. But when the command line argument changes, this rule is not triggerd

Here is my code:

Contents of `temp.mk`

```
ARG := $(basename $(filter %.ext,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))

# I want this rule to depend on value of ARG
# if the value from commandline changes then the rule should trigger dep.mk rule
# if I replace dep.mk rule with the below commented line , then it goes into infinite loop

#dep.mk : $(ARG)

dep.mk :  
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(shell touch $@)
    @echo "Creating dep.mk"

include dep.mk

%.ext : 
    @echo "in ext rule"

.PHONY : $(ARG)
```

Command to invoke the makefile :

```
make -f temp.mk foo.ext
```

Output :

```
mkdir -p ./
Creating dep.mk
in ext rule
```

Next time when I execute the makefile with different arguments :

```
make -f temp.mk bar.ext
```

Output :

```
in ext rule
```

Expected output :

```
mkdir -p ./
Creating dep.mk
in ext rule
```

If I depend directly on `$(ARG)` the makefile goes into an infinite loop. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Why do you want things to work this way? Is there an actual dependency relationship here? Make will examine the file system and run the recipes for the targets which are missing or out of date relative to their dependencies.

Comment: In the problem that I'm trying to solve, I want the dep.mk to hold some information formulated using command line arguments passed. This information will be used later for some further operations

Comment: If `dep.mk` really is a directory, you want to depend on something *in* that directory. A common trick is to `touch dep.mk/.$@` to mark `$@` as made, and have a rule like `%: dep.mk/.%` but I really still don't pretend to understand what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: For `make -f temp.mk foo.ext`, there is no rule that would match against `foo`, which is the value `$(ARG)` is expanded to. Similarly for `make -f temp.mk bar.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

On the first run, `dep.mk` doesn’t exist and is built because of the line saying `include dep.mk`. On subsequent runs, it exists and there is no dependency to check it against, so there is no reason for it to be re-made.

Declare it as `.PHONY` so it is built regardless:

```
ARG := $(basename $(filter %.ext,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))

dep.mk :  
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(shell touch $@)
    @echo "Creating dep.mk"

include dep.mk

%.ext : 
    @echo "in ext rule"

.PHONY : $(ARG) dep.mk
```

This is not what you want, however, because you want dep.mk to be built in dependency of $(ARG). But how can `make` know for which target dep.mk was built on previous runs? You have to keep separate *-dep.mk files for each target, this way:

```
ARG := $(basename $(filter %.ext,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))

$(ARG)-dep.mk :  
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(shell touch $@)
    @echo "Creating $@"

include $(ARG)-dep.mk

%.ext : 
    @echo "in ext rule"

.PHONY : $(ARG)
```

Of course, once built, this Makefile will never build a *-dep.mk again, unless you either include a `clean:` target which deletes all *-dep.mk or specify real dependencies forcing a rebuild when some of them become too old.